# Objective C Delegate for the Main Application Window

Tags: objective-c, delegates

So I'm trying to do this exercise where I need to set a delegate for the main window. The purpose is to make sure that when the user resizes the window, it's always twice as wide as it is high.

This is my AppController.h file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppController : NSObject
{
    NSWindow *windowWillResize;
}

@end
```

and this is my AppController.m file:

```
#import "AppController.h"

@implementation AppController

- (id) init
{
    [super init];
    windowWillResize = [[NSWindow alloc] init];
    [windowWillResize setDelegate:self];

    return self;
}

- (NSSize) windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender
                 toSize:(NSSize)frameSize;
{
    NSLog(@"size is changing");
    return frameSize;
}

@end
```

However, I can remove the line 
[windowWillResize setDelegate:self]; 
since I set the delegate in Interface Builder, but I'm not sure why this works.

How does windowWillResize know that I'm referring to the main application window since I'm doing a completely new 
windowWillResize = [[NSWindow alloc] init];

I have a feeling that I am completely doing this wrong. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you don't need to create a `NSWindow *windowWilResize` since a newly created Cocoa app already has a main window. You don't need to implement an `-init` method either.

You only need to set you appController as a delegate of your main window in Interface Builder and to implement the `-windowWillResize:` method in your appController.

If you are familiar with french language, you can take a look at a blog entry I have written on this subject: [Délégation en Cocoa](http://mouviciel.free.fr/blog/index.php?2008/09/04/38-delegation-en-cocoa-etre-et-avoir-premiere-partie).

Comment: Thank you both Graham and mouviciel.

I suspected that my creation of NSWindow was incorrect.

The thing I did not know was that windowWillResize is a built-in function.

So here's my next question, if I didn't use interface builder, is there anyway in my code to specify that I want appController to be the MainWindow's delegate?

Comment: Oh wait, now I'm confused... how does windowWillResize know to control the main window? I declared it in the header file, but nowhere do I connect it to the main window. I only set appController as the delegate... How does the windowWillResize function link to the actual resizing?

Comment: Setting appController as the delegate in Interface Builder is the way to connect -windowWillResize to the main window. Whenever a user requests a resizing of main window, the window instance sends a message [delegate windowWillResize:...] where delegate = appController.

Answer (score 2):

You're leaking an instance of `NSWindow`. In `-init` you create an `NSWindow` instance. However, that is not used because when the NIB loads, it sets up all the connections that you specified in Interface Builder and you start using the window from the NIB instead. Do not create a window object in code - Interface Builder does it for you! :-)

In fact, it's not quite "instead"; your app controller is now the delegate for *both* `NSWindow` instances - the one that comes from the NIB and the one you instantiated in `-init`. However as the in-code `NSWindow` is never used anywhere else, it's still redundant and should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to maintain the aspect ratio of the window you can use either of these two `NSWindow` methods:

- `setAspectRatio:(NSSize)`
- `setContentAspectRatio:(NSSize)`

The first method locks the entire window size, including the title bar. The second one just the content. You can call this method during the initialization of your window inside the delegate (for example: `-applicationDidFinishLaunching`)